# In a ReactNative project ! Why My ANDROID Gradle versions are different

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

in `Build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

where as in `graddle-wrapper.properties`, i have

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip
```

where these both are different? 
Can they cause an error being different in version?
please brief me in details.Thank you.

Comment: well brother! as The upvoted answer speaks for it self that distributionUrl is the actual version of the Gradle build system. 

classpath is the version of the Android Gradle plugin

Comment: nope they dont matter at all! can you tell which version of the React Native you are using with this npm image upload pkg! it worked for me with RN 0.56

Comment: I was using same .56 that time but now i updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, both of those versions are extremely outdated. The latest stable version for the `ditributionUrl` is 4.x. The latest stable for the `classpath` is 3.3.0.

The difference is this: the `distributionUrl` is the actual version of the Gradle build system. The `classpath` is the version of the Android Gradle *plugin*, not Gradle itself.

The versions you have tell me that you're either using an outdated version of Android Studio, or you ignored the popups telling you a newer version of Gradle was required for the newer version of Android Studio. You should probably update Android Studio to 3.3.